# React native - how can a function re-read current vars instead of using past values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there any way to re-pick or re-get all variables in react-native after you called the function?
For example let's say I have a const, a function and a button:

```
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('hi');
```

```
const foo = () => {
  while (true) {
    console.log(answer);
}}
```

```
<Button onPress={() => setAnswer("hello world!")} title="CLICK ME TO CHANGE THE ANSWER" />
```

Obviously the function would print "hi" over and over again but even when I click on the button and change the variable **answer** to "hello world!", the function still prints "hi" because it's stuck inside the while loop and can't read the current variable.
I know this code is very bad but this is just an example so no need to suggest another ways to do it.

thank you all in advance.

Comment: Try using `useCallback`? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(answser)
    }, [answer]);
```

It will print the value only when it changes.

Documentation :https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Comment: Thank you very much! If I understand correctly useEffect is special type of function, are there any options if I want to do it for multiple variables and I don't want to use only one function? out of curiosity, no real need right now.

Comment: you can declare as many useEffect you want, each will be triggered on specified variables in the array ( [answer1, answer2 ...] )